# What does 'opposite view' mean? (Picture)

Tags: meaning

I mean to ask about the "opposite view" of picture that is presented. How is it supposed to look like? Can I have an example please? 
For example, if I would point on this arrow, what is the opposite view of this arrow?

[image]

I looked for an answer on Google and I saw a lot of different pictures in different positions. Maybe here I can clarify the issue.

Comment: Context please! *Probably* "view" here means "opinion", hence "opposite view" means "different opinion". For instance, you might think that your question is fine as it is, I take the opposite view because I think it needs more context!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now is it clearer?

Comment: Do you mean to ask what position the photographer, for instance, need to occupy to take another shot of the same scene, only from "opposite view"?

Comment: Maybe because I'm not English native speaker I don't know how to express myself better. Forgive me about that, it's really no because I'm lazy but because I thought it's understood. Now I'm going to edit it again and to try to clear it more. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean "negative" perhaps?  "Inverted"?  Or do you think that the opposite of that arrow should be a similar arrow, only pointing to the right?

Comment: That's what I'm asking on. I would like to know the meaning, because I don't have the knowledge about this term.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a picture like this has an "opposite view"? I can imagine an arrow that points in the opposite _direction_, but the term "opposite view" usually applies to opinions, not pictures of arrows.

Comment: Where did you see this term and why do you think it applies to this image? Can you please explain what you're trying to understand?

Comment: I just want to understand what does it mean "opposite view" FOR EXAMPLE in relation to this picture. You can use in another picture (or in this picture with other position, I just took an example of position in order to get an answer referring to this picture) for the explaining what is the meaning of the term "opposite view" regarding to pictures. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only situation I can think of, as far as **pictures** are concerned, is that "*opposite view*" designates *a projection* (talking about 3-dimensional world shown on a 2-dimensional view) with the *inverted viewing vector* (usually the 'z' coordinate *after* the view transform).

For instance, a view *from the top* ("*top view*") might have the view *from the bottom* ("*bottom view*") as "opposite view".  Another example, a *front view* would have the *back view* as its opposite.  Those examples all talk about an object viewed from different sides.

It is also possible that the view of the environment by the "viewer" can be made *opposite*, although it's *less likely*.  Imagine yourself taking a photo by pointing your camera in *some direction*.  That direction is *an infinite line* crossing the center of your camera's objective lens.  Now imagine turning around and pointing your camera in the *opposite direction*, but *along the same line*.  That would also be an *opposite view*.

The phrase "opposite view" is really not common as far as pictures go.  It's used more to describe an opinion almost diametrically opposed to some given opinion.

Comment: Thank you. If I want for example to say that this bone is actually located in the right side, but I changed the side of the presentation from the right to left. What is the correct term to describe this case / this form of view?

Comment: @Assiduous - Was that the question you wanted to ask? Then why not ask it in the first place?